# ASP.Net MVC 4 C# login form with PhantomJS and Selenium

Tags: asp.net-mvc, selenium-webdriver, authentication, phantomjs

I have a specific question, as i can't figure out how to submit form without "id" or "name" in selenium.webdriver (phantomjs) there is html logim form:

```
<div class="ui-helper-child-2 ui-page-column-last ui-page-column-span-12">
<div class="ui-page-column-block ui-widget-signin">
  <h1>Sign In</h1>
  <form action="/glo/en-us/session,create/view.html" method="post">
    <div class="ui-helper-child-1">
      <label class="ui-state-required" for="username">Customer ID:</label>
      <input id="username" name="username" maxlength="9" type="text" value="" />
    </div>
    <div class="ui-helper-child-2">
      <label class="ui-state-required" for="password">Password:</label>
      <input id="password" name="password" maxlength="20" type="password" value="" />
    </div>
    <div class="ui-helper-child-3">
      <label class="ui-state-required" for="companyId">Company:</label>
      <select id="companyId" name="companyId">
        <option selected="selected" value="glo">Choose company</option>
        <option value="asp">new to asp</option>
        <option value="aeg">who is it</option>
        <option value="asus">who use this brand name</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-helper-child-4">
      <input id="callback" name="callback" type="hidden" value="/glo/en-us/home,show/view.html?error=1" />
      <input type="submit" value="Sign In" />
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

and one more time how to login? I can add information to  by webdriver.FindElement(username) and so on, but not know how to post data as i don't have id or name in submit element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will work for you:

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".ui-helper-child-4>[type='submit']")).Click();
```

Comment: Yes it works.. thank you. It looks i was too lazy to find elements.